# Jmeter JDBC request sampler not making UPDATEs

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, sql-update

I am using Jmeter 5 to run a simple SQL UPDTAE statement using JDBC Request sampler. After running the query ([Screenshot: JDBC Request][2])I can see in the result tree  window it says "1 updates" ([Screenshot: View Result Tree][1]), but when I check within the database I dont see the specific field is getting updated.
It doesn't seem to be a connection issue. When I run the same query from Management Studio the field is getting updated fine. Am I missing some settings in Jmeter?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Did you set Auto Commit true in JDBC Configuration?

Comment: I actually did not!I had it set at default value False, and changing it to True solved the problem. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set true in Auto Commit of [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

> Turn auto commit on or off for the connections.